# Find and replace all occurrences of old image name with new name within HTML pages

Tags: php, preg-match, str-replace

After I rename an image I would like to perform a search on all HTML Pages within a directory. The idea is to find all pages with the old name and update the page with new name.

I am having a problem with the string replacement portion.

```
$files = glob('/directory/*.html');
foreach($files AS $file) {
   $html = file_get_contents($file);
   $find = "old.jpg";
   preg_match("#src=(\"?|'?)(http://www.domain.com/images/|/images/)?$find(\"?|'?)#si", $html, $image);
   if (!empty($image[1])) {

       //find and replace all occurrences within page I need help with.

       $write = fopen($file, 'w');
       fwrite($write, $new_html);
       fclose($write);
    }
}
```

**Examples of what I am searching for and replacing.**

Find src="/images/old.jpg" replace src="/images/new.jpg"

Find src="http://www.domain.com/images/old.jpg replace src="http://www.domain.com/images/new.jpg"

Find src="/old.jpg ignore

Find src="http://www.anyotherdomain/old.jpg ignore

Comment: Ouch! You can't just echo the URLs dynamically in your pages?

Comment: Why not just have PHP pages that include the URL to the image as a variable?

Comment: These are Static HTML Pages not PHP. When I client changes an image by renaming it, I would like to change the image references as well.

Answer (score 0):

A ***FAR*** superior solution would be to include a constant with the image name in every webpage and use ti to reference your image path.

#### constants.inc.php

```
<?php
    define('IMAGE_PATH', 'absolute/path/to/image.jpg');
?>
```

#### anyotherpage.php

```
<?php require_once('constants.inc.php'); ?>
...
...
...
<img src="<?php echo IMAGE_PATH ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Replace in Files

It's probably easiest to just do a **find and replace in files** using a text editor that supports it.

- [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/): Read the [find/replace docs](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/searching/replacing)
- [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2): Find -> Find in Files

There is similar functionality in many IDEs (usually "find in files" or "find in project"), but there's more setup involved if you aren't using them already.

#### Using PHP

If you absolutely *have* to use PHP you'll want to use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). You can test your regex using a regex tool like [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) or [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) (there are tons of regex testers online), or a text editor that supports regex.

#### Two bits of advice

1. Backup or version your files before you batch modify them like this.
2. Don't be afraid to search / replace with multiple patterns to get all of the different cases.